# vite does not log anything to console

Tags: vite

When I configure vite via the config file

```
export default {
    logLevel: 'info'
}
```

or via commandline

```
vite -l info
```

then I still see no logs on Windows. When I configre warn or info, then vite hangs.

How can I see logs with vite?

Answer (score 1):

If You are searching logs from terminal try **browser** console (ctrl-shift-i) instead.